# Pandas: increase speed of rolling window (apply a custom function)

Tags: python, performance, dataframe, median, rolling-computation

I'm using this code to apply a function (`funcX`) on my data-frame using a rolling window. The main issue is that the size of this data-frame (`data`) is very large, and I'm searching for a faster way to do this task.

```
import numpy as np

def funcX(x):
    x = np.sort(x)
    xd = np.delete(x, 25)
    med = np.median(xd)
    return (np.abs(x - med)).mean() + med

med_out = data.var1.rolling(window = 51, center = True).apply(funcX, raw = True)
```

The only reason for using this function is that the calculated median is the median after removing the middle value. So it's different with adding `.median()` at the end of the rolling window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be effective, a window algorithm must link the results of two overlaying windows.

Here, with : `med0` the median, `med` the median of  `x \ med0`, `xl` elements before `med` and `xg` elements after `med`in the sorted elements, `funcX(x)` can be seen as :

```
<|x-med|> + med = [sum(xg) - sum(xl) - |med0-med|] / windowsize + med
```

So an idea it to maintain a buffer which represents the sorted current window, `sum(xg)` and `sum(xl)`. Using Numba just in time compilation, very good performance arise here.

First the buffer management:

`init` sorts the first window and compute left(`xls`) and right(`xgs`) sums.

```
import numpy as np
import numba
windowsize = 51 #odd, >1
halfsize = windowsize//2

@numba.njit
def init(firstwindow):
    buffer = np.sort(firstwindow)
    xls = buffer[:halfsize].sum()
    xgs = buffer[-halfsize:].sum()   
    return buffer,xls,xgs
```

`shift` is the linear part. It updates the buffer, maintaining it sorted . `np.searchsorted` computes positions of insertion and deletion in `O(log(windowsize))`. It's technical since `xin<xout` and `xout<xin` are not symmetrical situations.

```
@numba.njit
def shift(buffer,xin,xout):
    i_in = np.searchsorted(buffer,xin) 
    i_out = np.searchsorted(buffer,xout)
    if xin <= xout :
        buffer[i_in+1:i_out+1] = buffer[i_in:i_out] 
        buffer[i_in] = xin                        
    else:
        buffer[i_out:i_in-1] = buffer[i_out+1:i_in]                      
        buffer[i_in-1] = xin
    return i_in, i_out
```

`update` updates the buffer and the sums of left and right parts. It's technical since `xin<xout` and `xout<xin` are not symmetrical situations.

```
@numba.njit
def update(buffer,xls,xgs,xin,xout):
    xl,x0,xg = buffer[halfsize-1:halfsize+2]
    i_in,i_out = shift(buffer,xin,xout)

    if i_out < halfsize:
        xls -= xout
        if i_in <= halfsize:
            xls += xin
        else:    
            xls += x0
    elif i_in < halfsize:
        xls += xin - xl

    if i_out > halfsize:
        xgs -= xout
        if i_in > halfsize:
            xgs += xin
        else:    
            xgs += x0
    elif i_in > halfsize+1:
        xgs += xin - xg

    return buffer, xls, xgs
```

`func` is equivalent to the original `funcX` on buffer. `O(1)`.

```
@numba.njit       
def func(buffer,xls,xgs):
    med0 = buffer[halfsize]
    med  = (buffer[halfsize-1] + buffer[halfsize+1])/2
    if med0 > med:
        return (xgs-xls+med0-med) / windowsize + med
    else:               
        return (xgs-xls+med-med0) / windowsize + med
```

`med` is the global function. `O(data.size * windowsize)`.

```
@numba.njit
def med(data):
    res = np.full_like(data, np.nan)
    state = init(data[:windowsize])
    res[halfsize] = func(*state)
    for i in range(windowsize, data.size):
        xin,xout = data[i], data[i - windowsize]
        state = update(*state, xin, xout)
        res[i-halfsize] = func(*state)
    return res
```

Performance :

```
import pandas
data=pandas.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10**5))

%time res1=data[0].rolling(window = windowsize, center = True).apply(funcX, raw = True)
Wall time: 10.8 s

res2=med(data[0].values)

np.allclose((res1-res2)[halfsize:-halfsize],0)
Out[112]: True

%timeit res2=med(data[0].values)
40.4 ms ± 462 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

it's ~ 250X faster, with window size = 51. An hour becomes 15 seconds.